# Not able to fetch array in view. Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel-5, fetch

I'm trying to fetch arrays passed from controller. 
In controller i have used following code:

```
 foreach ($sfees as $sfee) {
    $M_fees[]=M_fees::all()->whereLoose('id',$sfee->mfee_id);


 };


return view('bill.verify',compact('bfs','grade','student'))->with('M_fees',$M_fees);
```

In view:
I have used following:

```
@foreach($M_fees as $M_Fees)
                <tr class="info">
                    <td>{!!$M_Fees['fee_type']!!}</td>
                    <td>{!!$M_Fees['amount']!!}</td>

@endforeach
```

But it shows error of "Undefined index:fee_type".
But if i just echo

```
@foreach($M_fees as $M_Fees)
    {!!$M_Fees!!} 
 @endforeach
```

it is showing whole bunch of arrays like:

[{"id":1,"fee_type":"Sports","amount":5000,"created_at":"2016-06-07 08:33:40","updated_at":"2016-06-07 08:33:40"}]

{"1":{"id":2,"fee_type":"Fine","amount":20,"created_at":"2016-06-08 05:16:59","updated_at":"2016-06-08 05:16:59"}}

{"2":{"id":3,"fee_type":"Transportation","amount":500,"created_at":"2016-06-08 05:17:17","updated_at":"2016-06-08 05:17:17"}}

Which includes fee_type and both amount. What is the problem? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the data in view like this :

```
foreach ($sfees as $sfee) {
    $M_fees[]=M_fees::all()->whereLoose('id',$sfee->mfee_id);
}

$data["M_fees"] = $M_fees;
return view('bill.verify',$data);
```

**Hope, this answer will solve your problem.**